# Is is possible to write a CSS selector for the interaction of TD and COL/COLGROUP elements?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors

I'm using the COLGROUP and COL elements for the first time, to highlight specific columns of a data table.  There are also special rows of my table such as the header, footer, and perhaps highlighted rows as well.  I'm not finding it straightforward to assign a style to the intersection of a row and column style.  Is it possible to write such a CSS selector?

Simple example:

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col span="2">
    <col class="col_highlight">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th> <th>Sales</th> <th>Profit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tools</td> <td>$12,345.67</td> <td>$345.67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Books</td> <td>$8,910.11</td> <td>$910.11</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The third column is highlighted with style `col_highlight` (just a different background color).  I want that special color to show up in the table body (`<TD>` elements) and not in the header (`<TH>` element).  What's the CSS selector for those cells?  I've tried...

- `td .col_highlight`
- `td.col_highlight`
- `.col_highlight td`

Comment: Nop. if its about thead tr not showing the highlighted col bg, then set a bg-color to its tr and, col bg-color will be hidden:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRgZya

Comment: Not sure I *exactly* understand what you're going after. Could you draw a simple graphic example demonstrating the effect you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selectors level 4 introduces the [column combinator](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-column-combinator) for this purpose, but no implementations exist and the feature itself is at-risk:

```
.col_highlight || td
```

The need for a new combinator arises because the TDs aren't descendants of the COL element and vice versa, so none of the selectors you've tried that use the descendant combinator will work. The TDs don't themselves have the class, so compounding the two selectors won't work either.

Unfortunately, I can't see any workarounds other than applying classes to the TH and TD elements and targeting them directly instead of relying on the COLGROUP and COL elements (which is the entire reason why the column combinator was introduced in the first place, and why I really hope it gets implemented, though I'm sure performance junkies will disagree and claim that you're better off bloating your markup with classes on all the cell elements either way).